# Slicing with :-1 and None - What does each of the statement mean?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I came across a code snippet where I could not understand two of the statements, though I could see the end result of each.

I will create a variable before giving the statements:

```
train = np.random.random((10,100))
```

One of them read as :

```
train = train[:-1, 1:-1]
```

What does this slicing mean? How to read this? I know that that `-1` in slicing denotes from the back. But I cannot understand this.

Another statement read as follows:

```
la = [0.2**(7-j) for j in range(1,t+1)]
np.array(la)[:,None]
```

What does slicing with `None` as in `[:,None]` mean?

For the above two statements, along with how each statement is read, it will be helpful to have an alternative method along, so that I understand it better.

Comment: Have you gone through the docs - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing? That `None` is an alias for `np.newaxis`, generally used for broadcasting - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: create small array with not-random data and then see results - and you will better see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of Python's strengths is its uniform application of straightforward principles. Numpy indexing, like all indexing in Python, passes a single argument to the indexed object's (*i.e.*, the array's) `__getitem__` method, and numpy arrays were one of the primary justifications for the slicing mechanism (or at least one of its very early uses).

When I'm trying to understand new behaviours I like to start with a concrete and comprehensible example, so rather than 10x100 random values I'll start with a one-dimensional 4-element vector and work up to 3x4, which should be big enough to understand what's going on.

```
simple = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

train = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

The interpreter shows these as

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

The expression `simple[x]` is equivalent to (which is to say the interpreter ends up executing) `simple.__getitem__(x)` under the hood - note this call takes a single argument.

The numpy array's `__getitem__` method implements indexing with an integer very simply: it selects a single element from the first dimension. So `simple[1]` is `2`, and `train[1]` is `array([5, 6, 7, 8])`.

When `__getitem__` receives a tuple as an argument (which is how Python's syntax interprets expressions like `array[x, y, z]`) it applies each element of the tuple as an index to successive dimensions of the indexed object. So `result = train[1, 2]` is equivalent (conceptually - the code is more complex in implementation) to

```
temp = train[1]    # i.e. train.__getitem__(1)
result = temp[2]   # i.e. temp.__getitem__(2)
```

and sure enough we find that `result` comes out at `7`. You could think of `array[x, y, z]` as equivalent to `array[x][y][z]`.

Now we can add slicing to the mix. Expressions containing a colon can be regarded as *slice literals* (I haven't seen a better name for them), and the interpreter creates [*slice* objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) for them. As the documentation notes, a slice object is mostly a container for three values, *start*, *stop* and *slice*, and it's up to each object's `__getitem__` method how it interprets them. You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) helpful to understand slicing further.

With what you now know, you should be able to understand the answer to your first question.

```
result = train[:-1, 1:-1]
```

will call `train.__getitem__` with a two-element tuple of slices. This is equivalent to

```
temp = train[:-1]
result = temp[..., 1:-1]
```

The first statement can be read as "set `temp` to all but the last row of `train`", and the second as "set `result` to all but the first and last columns of `temp`". `train[:-1]` is

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

and applying the `[1:-1]` subscripting to the second dimension of that array gives

```
array([[2, 3],
       [6, 7]])
```

The ellipsis on the first dimension of the `temp` subscript says "pass everything," so `the subscript expression`[...]`can be considered equivalent to`[:]`. As far as the`None`values are concerned, a slice has a maximum of three data points: _start_, _stop_ and _step_. A`None`value for any of these gives the default value, which is`0`for _start_, the length of the indexed object for _stop_, and`1`for _step. So`x[None:None:None]`is equivalent to`x[0:len(x):1]`which is equivalent to`x[::]`.

With this knowledge under your belt you should stand a bit more chance of understanding what's going on.